# ios: Changing UILabel.text resize UIImageView when text change

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uilabel

I encounter a strange behavior in my application.
I did a simple code to reproduce this.

The `stepper` increment and decrement 10 by 10 with min value 0 and maximum 200 and start with 100.
Depends if the value is greater than 100 the `label.text` has different value. There is also a button that set the value to a default value.
The width of the `osImage` is set to the value of the stepper.
Everything is fine until the `label.text` change, everytime the `label.text` change the `osImage` goes back it's original size.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var stepper: UIStepper!
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var osImage: UIImageView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        label.text = "Default text"
        osImage.bounds.size.width = 100
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    @IBAction func onButton(_ sender: Any) {
        label.text = "Default Value !"
    }

    @IBAction func onStepChange(_ sender: UIStepper) {
        print(stepper.value)
        if stepper.value > 100 {
            label.text = "Too big !"
        } else {
            label.text = "I'm so small !"
        }
        osImage.bounds.size.width = CGFloat(stepper.value)
    }

}
```

Please I need some help to understand and counter this behavior.

Comment: Are you using constraints in you storyboard ? If so that's probably your issue. Your image view width should be managed by a constraint as well.

Comment: @deadbeef Yes that was the problem, now if I set the constraint programmatically it works ! Thanks a lot !